Issue with EV2 YAML Approval Service Not Displaying Deployment Review
We are experiencing an issue with the EV2 YAML Approval Service in our project. According to the documentation, we have configured security groups in the Release and Deployment Approvers tab within the service tree portal for EC Tools. However, it appears that the approval service is only recognizing one approver instead of both the technical and deployment approvers as expected.
Here's what I've done so far:

Verified the configuration of security groups for both approvers.
Checked the service tree portal settings for any discrepancies.
Reviewed the related wiki documentation for any missed steps.

What steps can I take to ensure that both approvers are recognized during the deployment review process?

Hi there, Welcome to SO. Since you are reaching out to Azure DevOps subcommunity, may I assume you encountered issues with the Azure DevOps release pipelines? Can you share some screenshots to help understand the current pipeline definition? And what documentation did you review to configure your approvers? Can you elaborate more on the behavior your observed? Please don't forget to scrub/remove the sensitive information when updating your original post. Thx.

Could you please provide more details of your pipeline, or the simplest example that demonstrates the problem? When you say, is only recognizing one approver instead of both, do you mean that one approval is sufficient and you want two approvals to be the minimum? Alternatively, are there specific people who can't approve even though you want them to be able?
